How to set pip's user installation folder other than the home folder?
While installing a package using pip, installation defaults to user installation because normal site-packages are not writeable. But eventually could not install packages due to OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device. This is only natural as my home folder is quite small. So, my question would be how to handle installation folder in such a case?

Simply use -t, --target <dir> to install packages into <dir>. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>. Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in <dir> with new versions.
